# Is the Google Tag Manager container automatically refreshed? If so, how/where?

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

I'm not clear on if the Google Tag Manager `Container` is automatically refreshed, and if so how.

The documentation states:

> By default, your container becomes eligible to be refreshed every 12 hours. To manually refresh the container, use `ContainerHolder.refresh()`:
>
> `ContainerHolderSingleton.getContainerHolder().refresh();`
>
> This is an asynchronous call that will not return immediately. To reduce network traffic, `refresh()` may only be called once every 15 minutes, otherwise it will be a no-op.

It's the "becomes eligible to be refreshed every 12 hours" paired with the "To manually refresh" part that is tripping me up. As such I have two questions:

1. Does Google Tag Manager attempt to refresh the `Container` every 12 hours?
2. If the answer to #1 is yes then where/how does this occur?

My assumption at this point is that the answer to #1 is "Yes".

My concern is that I'm not sure where this automatic refresh occurs and I only access the `getContainer()` in the `ContainerAvailableListener` and then cache the values. So if it's the `getContainer()` call that triggers the update, like happens with the "swapping" of a new container, my implementation might not be refreshing.

**Edit:** My reason for asking is that the lifetime of my application can be quite long. I'm trying to determine if I need to manage container refreshes in my code or not.